# Penalising page breaks within environment

Tags: page-breaking

I have an environment that I use to format examples in a document I'm writing.  The contents of that environment typically consists of a few short paragraphs, often each only a line or two long. I sometimes find one line separated on the next or previous page, but because the lines are usually one-line paragraphs, LaTeX doesn't consider them widows or 
orphans, so `\clubpenalty` and `\widowpenalty` don't apply.

What I'd like to do is have LaTeX consider the whole of the environment to be a single paragraph for the purpose of penalising widows and orphans; or add an additional penalty to any page breaks that fall within the environment.  I don't expect them to stop entirely, but I'm seeing plenty of breaks that I'm sure LaTeX could avoid if it knew to do so.

Not sure that a MWE really adds anything, but here's one anyway.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mdframed,parskip,color,xcolor,lipsum}
\mdfsetup{leftmargin=2em,linewidth=3pt,
  rightline=false,topline=false,bottomline=false,
  skipabove=1em,skipbelow=0.25em}

\definecolor{examplebg}{HTML}{E9FBE9}
\definecolor{exampleln}{HTML}{9999FF}
\newmdenv[backgroundcolor=examplebg,linecolor=exampleln]{examplebox}
\newenvironment{example}{\begin{examplebox}%
  \textit{Example} --- \ignorespaces}%
  {\end{examplebox}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{example}
\lipsum
\end{example}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to prevent page breaks within the environment?

Comment: Preventing them is easy.  Just use `minipage`.  No, I want to penalise them, so they're less likely to occur.